# Como guardar texto em arquivo, XML ou TXT ou HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, string, arquivo

Eu estou a desenvolver um programa em C# e gostaria de saber como guardar o texto de uma `RichTextBox` em formato `.xml` ou `.html` ou `.txt`.

Comment: Você já tem algum código desenvolvido para colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: Não mas postei essa pergunta pois eu sou iniciante e então eu não sei fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não dá detalhes mas a forma mais simples de fazer isto é usando o [`WriteAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_):

```
File.WriteAllText(caminhoCompletoDoArquivo, seuRichTextBox.Text);
```

Este método é pronto para o que deseja. Como o próprio nome diz ele escreve um texto no arquivo especificado em `caminhoCompletoDoArquivo`) não precisa ser uma variável, pode ser um texto com o caminho do arquivo, ex.: "c:\minhaApp\xml.txt") e ele pegará o conteúdo a ser gravado diretamente o controle através da propriedade `Text` do objeto `seuRichTextBox`.

Para ler:

```
var texto = File.ReadAllText(caminhoCompletoDoArquivo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/TextFile.cs).

Documentação do [`ReadAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_).

Evidentemente que os dados em formato XML e HTML devem estar em ordem. A gravação não garante nada. Estes métodos só fazer a gravação de um texto sem saber o que ele significa e se está certo.